# UWP Designer Stopped Working

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-designer

So I have been working on this UWP project (visual studio 2017) for months and just recently the designer stopped working (it shows Loading desinger... You can continue working while the designer is loading in the background.) I have tried getting an earlier, working version of the project, but this did nothing to resolve the issue. One thing that did help was I made a in place copy of the folder containing the solution/projects. Opening this solution (with identical code) works as intended. So is there some temp files or something that is stopping the original version from working properly? I guess a solution I could use is to just work off the new copied directory, but if another solution is available I'd rather use that since this may happen again. Not sure why it happened in the first place honestly. Any information and/or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if your vs2017 works fine with other project types which is using designer window you need to reinstall your related SDK, if you have vs2015 also you can cross check by creating new universal project and if same problem also on vs2015 then you need to uninstall and reinstall related  sdk and if vs2015 works fine with same project then you need to reinstall your vs2017 installation :|

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeting the Fall Creators Update (16299), then Visual Studio will use the new XAML Designer, which although usually being more precise with its presentation is still more buggy and I find it more often not working than working. But it is a work in progress and I am actually extremely happy it is being improved :-) .

In any case, I think you can delete the temporary files and folders for the project like `bin`, `obj`, `.suo`, etc. and then `Clean the solution` and `Rebuild all`. If the copy-paste approach works, I suspect there is a stuck temporary file that causes this.

Comment: The app is targeting 16299. I tried deleting the files (I've even deleted the entire directory and got everything from perforce again. The problem is still there after a rebuild. So far the only option I see is to create a new directory/workspace and work from there. This will be less than ideal if the issue happens again.

Comment: My projects (UWP and WPF) since I targeted 16299, any time I open a xaml the designer shows up fine but VS completely locks up for like 90 seconds or so. If I work in it for a few minutes it will lock up again for 90 seconds.  I deleted bin and obj and cleaned solution but nothing changed.  Completely unusable. I've been keeping busy with other stuff but eventually I'll need it.  Maybe Blend will work.

Comment: Also I'm using the new Color Picker so I have to target 16299.

Comment: New version of Visual Studio was just released - 15.5. You can try updating and see if it helps.